# mac os mp3 auto-tag

Tags: mac, mp3, music

is there any good tool in mac os for auto-tag mp3 files? 
like in windows there are Winamp send to -> auto-tag, which uses gracenote database to tag mp3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Picard_Tagger)

[image: Screenshot of MusicBrainz Picard]